# SaltStack: Can I test targeting expressions in a state or module?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to setup users on hosts. The users are split to groups, e.g admins, users, etc...

I want to tag each host with a list of which groups users should be present on it. i.e ideally I would be able to do this from pillar:

```
base:
  '*':
    - user_groups: [admins]

  'env: qa* AND role: frontend':
    - user_groups: [users, ci]
```

Right now I have to prepare files with various permutations if I want to do this from pillar.

I was thinking I can have a single pillar with expressions like so:

```
server_user_groups:
  '*': [admins]

  'env: qa* AND role: frontend': [users, ci]
```

Then from my state I can iterate this structure:

```
{% for target, groups in pillar.server_user_groups if salt.check_target(target) %}
  # Include this group of users on this host...
{% endfor %}
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it...

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.match.html

```
{% for target, groups in pillar.server_user_groups if salt['match.compound'](target) %}
  # Include this group of users on this host...
{% endfor %}
```